# Laravel Mail / Swift / How to globally configure "sender" address

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, sendmail, swiftmailer

Laravel offers the config `mail.from` to allow specifying a global/default `From` address. This calls `setFrom` on the Swift-Message internally and sets the "*Header From*" that shows in the recipients email client. 
However, the message is then also sent with *Return-Path/Envelope-From* of this value, because of [`getReversePath`](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/7ffc1ea296ed14bf8260b6ef11b80208dbadba91/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php#L336-L355), that derives this *From* value as no other option (*Sender/Return-Path*) has been set.

The site is running on a multi-project host with Exim4 running locally, so there are no restrictions to set these addresses like if I was using something like Gmail SMTP. 
Laravel is configured to use `sendmail`.

Let's assume the machines hostname is `webX.hosts.our-company-intern.com` and the project that runs on it belongs to a subdomain of `customer-brand.com`. E-Mails should be sent from the "main-domain" (without the subdomain part), though, like `noreply@customer-brand.com`. `customer-brand.com.` does not resolve to the machine the subdomain project is hosted.

I would like to send the mail with an Envelope address of my actual hostname (better: preserve the default *Envelope-From/Return-Path* Exim/Sendmail would use), like `appname@webX.hosts.our-company-intern.com` and only have `From: noreply@customer-brand.com`.

Reason for that is, I'd like to have a valid *Return-Path* indicating from which host it actually came from. 
SPF is also a reason, but not the main one; we control the `customer-brand.com` domain and could just add our hosts address, I'd still like to avoid it if possible and use our domain that already have all our hosts in their SPF record.

When I put the following line in the [Laravel vendor class-method `Mailer::send`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1062a22232071c3e8636487c86ec1ae75681bbf9/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L210):

```
$message->sender('appname@webX.hosts.our-company-intern.com');
```

This yields my desired result, but of course I cannot just edit it in vendor code. 
**Where can I configure this properly (maybe via a callback that executes for every message)? Or isn't there any such option and I should write an issue in the Laravel/Mail package?**

I also tried putting `-f` in the sendmail command: 
`/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -f"appname@webX.hosts.our-company-intern.com"` 
- however this already fails at the `_establishProcessConnection()`. Called in CLI the error is:

> exim: incompatible command-line options or arguments

---

Versions:

- Laravel 5.4.36
- Swiftmailer 5.4.9
- Exim 4.89-2+deb9u2

Config `mail.php`:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => 'noreply@customer-brand.com',
    'name' => 'Customer Brand',
],
```

Tinker-Shell test code:

```
Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function($message) {
  $message->to('my-personal-email-for-testing@domain.com');
})
```

Current mail headers:

```
Received: from webX.hosts.our-company-intern.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) by ...
Received: from appname (helo=[127.0.0.1])
    by webX.hosts.our-company-intern.com with local-smtp (Exim 4.89)
    (envelope-from <noreply@customer-brand.com>)  // this should change
    ...
From: Customer Brand <noreply@customer-brand.com>
Return-Path: noreply@customer-brand.com  // this should change
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the top of my head: you could hook in the `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` event and add the sender there.

Given the corporate environment I'll assume you know how to [listen to events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events#registering-events-and-listeners) (if not, let me know). In that case, here's the listener you'll need:

```
class MessageSendingListener
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {
        // $event->message is of type \Swift_Message
        // So you'll need the setSender() method here.

        $event->message->setSender('appname@webX.hosts.our-company-intern.com');
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems I missed that Event when I scanned the Mailer class code. Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As written by [Sajal Soni](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-emails-in-laravel--cms-30046)

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class DemoEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The demo object instance.
     *
     * @var Demo
     */
    public $demo;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($demo)
    {
        $this->demo = $demo;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('sender@example.com')
                    ->view('mails.demo')
                    ->text('mails.demo_plain')
                    ->with(
                      [
                            'testVarOne' => '1',
                            'testVarTwo' => '2',
                      ])
                      ->attach(public_path('/images').'/demo.jpg', [
                              'as' => 'demo.jpg',
                              'mime' => 'image/jpeg',
                      ]);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: I don't think this answer applies to the question. You call `from` which leads to the same problem, and I don't see code that sets the "envelope sender". The linked tutorial is a beginner explanation how to send emails at all, only.

Answer (score 0):

**Mention  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=dev@example.com  in .env file**

Then run:

php artisan config:cache

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=dev@example.com
```